# Three.js - Load .3dxml or .smgxml file formats in html

Tags: javascript, three.js, autocad

We wanted to embed a 3d object with `.3dxml` file format in html page

Now `Three.js` does not support these formats, is there any Js library or converter which can convert `.3dxml` or `.smgxml` file in to compatible formats supported by `Three.js` or any other JS library which can render it to html?

Also these files were exported from `AutoCad`, can anybody suggest any supported formats which `AutoCad` can export and can be used to embed to html.

Comment: Give `FBX` a try. `AutoCad` supports this format as an export option. You can load the asset in `three.js` via `FBXLoader`.

Comment: Thnx, will definitely ask my team for this format, also is there a way i can do it without using autocad?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe you find a converter via google.